# Component Identification - NTC? PTC? ϑ? [BMW Z4 E85 Heated Seats]

Tags: automotive, ptc

I'm trying to identify a part in a circuit that has next to zero information out there on the web other than the wiring diagram itself direct from BMW's NEWTIS.

I'm trying to fathom out what the circled component is.  I *think* it's a PTC, with the theta symbol (ϑ) meaning the resistance increases with the temperature but was hoping someone would recognise it and be able to give me clarification or correction.

[image]

Comment: I think NTCs are more common as thermal sensors than PTCs.  Also the wires are called *NTC*FA and HZFA.

Comment: Theta just means temperature, I don't believe it corresponds to PTC. See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/581636/2028

Comment: @OskarSkog - well spotted, I hadn't twigged that!

Comment: At least on this Z4 you don’t have to pay BMW a subscription to use your heated seats… https://www.thedrive.com/news/bmw-responds-to-fury-over-heated-seats-subscription-fee

Comment: Not a BMW, but when I retrofitted a Recaro seat, it was a big standard 10k NTC in it for temperature read back.

Comment: Haha @hacktastical, like oscilloscope manufacturers do ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol just means it is a device with temperature coefficient.

There is no indication in the symbol itself to which direction the coefficient is, and the symbols that would indicate the coefficient direction are missing.

However, it seems that it is a component used to measure temperature, and generally an NTC is more useful for that. PTCs are generally more useful for other purposes.

Also the text on the diagram says NTC, so there is very little indication it would be anything else than an NTC.